# Send command to SQL Server to kill query mid execution if it reaches x time

Tags: c#, sql-server

Given a connection to a SQL Server database via C#, I want to be able to send a command to the database to halt the execution of a large query if it takes over a certain amount of seconds.

From my understanding [`CommandTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) is the C# handle that measures (in seconds) the time to wait for the command to execute. However it doesn't tell the database to end the execution on its end.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(database.ConnectionString))
 {
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 30;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

    //send command to SQL Server to kill Query Session ID if takes over 30s

    da.Fill(response);
    connection.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
```

I researched using [SqlCommand.Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) but am unsure how to implement it or if it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue with CommandTimeout is? - i.e. what does it do/not do that you require?

Comment: The SqlCommmand.CommandTimout property does send a cancel command (attention event) to the server to cancel the executing query on the server.

Comment: It is my understanding that CommandTimeout does not kill the session id for the query running in the sql server db

Comment: @Tanner I'm building a system that allows clients to interface a database and want to limit large joins and aggregate queries that could take minutes.

Comment: @BDillan you do that with the command timeout. What's the problem?

Comment: @BDillan besides, why should you care about the *connection* when you want to cancel the *command*? The connection, what you call session, will close when you call `Close()` on it. You need to remove the manual calls to `Close()` and `Dispose()` though and put anything that needs disposal into `using()` blocks. *Disposing* a connection means closing it

Comment: @BDillan besides, you *won't* reach the line after `Fill` unless the command completes or times out.

Comment: If you are still unsure about the advice given above you could test it. Execute the query text (from the SqlCommand) `WAITFOR TIME '0:30'` and set the command timeout to 15 seconds (these numbers are arbitrary). You can profile the database to see what happens or use the activity monitor in SSMS.

Comment: You can use below tables to find session ID and kill it .           Tables: sys.dm_exec_sessions ,
 sys.dm_exec_requests